# How do I read X file into RAM as a number in C++ in a linux environment?

Tags: c++, file, numbers, ram, gmp

I'm working on a compression program which needs to read a file into RAM as a single number and perform basic math operations and bit shifting.  I've looked at gmp from GNU, but that has such poor integration into c/c++ I have no idea where to begin to read and put the values into the mpz_t variable.

Comment: That sure is gonna be one big, badass number.

Comment: How does having explicit classes with overloaded operators translate into "poor integration"?

Comment: Can't use standard c++ mathematical operators.  That's poor integration, or moreover, no integration to the standard library.

Comment: It does have overloaded operators; I just checked the [docs.](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-General)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

mpz_class fileToNumber (const string& fileName)
{
    mpz_class number;
    ifstream file(fileName.c_str());
    while( file.good() ){
        unsigned char c;
        file >> c;
        number <<= 8;
        number += c;
    }
    file.close();
    return number;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( argc - 1 < 1 ){
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " file.txt" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << hex << fileToNumber(argv[1]) << endl;
}
```

Edit: Fixed, misunderstood the original question, now it reads files as a number instead of an ASCII number.

Edit: Moved the entire file to mpz_class conversion into a nice function.

Comment: That won't even compile on my machine.

Comment: Compile it with -lgmp -lgmpxx. By the way the file contains the number as ASCII characters right?

Comment: No, any file.  I'm testing it with OS .iso files and such.

Comment: I have to ask since I'm not familiar

Comment: with the expended main function, how do I tell it the file?  I'm sorry for not knowing this, but no class I've had has covered this.

Comment: Moved the entire logic into a function. Its use should be clear, just copypaste it into your code, with includes and namespace use.

Comment: Very nice code!  Ideas on speeding it up, or is that another subject?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about speed if it is for experimentation only. Only optimize when your program is nearing completion, with all of its planned features working. I doubt you could speed it up by much though.

Comment: Well, in my experience, when instantiating anything in a loop like that causes a memory leak if the loop runs faster than the garbage collector, so if possible, NEVER INSTANTIATE NEW VARIABLES WITHIN A LOOP :P

Comment: @Josh: Garbage collector?  In C++?  There isn't one!  You need to adjust your intuition a bit, if you're coming from a Java background.  Your warning about instantiating new variables in a loop is not really a consideration in C++; in fact, we rely heavily on the fact that an object's destructor is executed precisely when that object goes out of scope. Look up "RAII" some time; it's an important concept in C++ programming.